# How do I print exact sentence by filtering using regular expression in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm new to regular expression and got stuck with the code below.

```
import re
s = "5. Consider the task in Figure 8.11, which are balanced in fig 99.2"
output = re.findall((r'[A-Z][a-z]*'), s)[0]
output2 = re.findall(r'\b[^A-Z\s\d]+\b', s)

mixing = " ".join(str(x) for x in output2)
   

finalmix = output+" " + mixing
print(finalmix)
```

Here I'm trying to print "Consider the task in Figure 8.11, which are balanced in fig 99.2" from the given string s' as a sentence in output. So I joined the two outputs using join statement at the end to get it as a sentence. But its a lot confusing now since "Figure 8.11" and "fig 99.2"  will not be printed as I have not given a regex code for that because I cannot determine what regex I should be using and later combining it at the end.

It's probably because I'm using a wrong approach to print the given sentence from the string s. I'll be glad if anyone could help me fix the code or guide me using some alternate approach as this code looks absurd.

This is the output I get:

```
Consider the task in . which are balanced in .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture all bulleted items, I would use:

```py
import re
s = "5. Consider the task in Figure 8.11, which are balanced in fig 99.2"
items = re.findall(r'\d+\.(?!\d)(.*?)(?=\d+\.(?!\d)|$)', s, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(items)
```

This prints:

```
['Consider the task in Figure 8.11, which are balanced in fig 99.2']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```regex
\d+\.              match a bulleted number
(?!\d)             which is NOT followed by another number
(.*?)              match and capture all content, across newlines, until hitting
(?=\d+\.(?!\d)|$)  another number bullet OR the end of the input
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It looks like I only know the very basics of regex . I have never used some of the terms you mentioned here and I think that's the reason I made this look so difficult. I'll learn from this surely :)

Comment: Can we use multiple regex on a single sentence? Like suppose the string varies every time. If I have to find this "5. Consider the task in Figure 8.11, which are balanced in fig 99.2 in the question" the next time? Can I use an 'or' statement and give two regex codes ? Can regular expression manage multiple regexes at the same time? Hope you can understand :)

Comment: I don't follow because I don't know the alternative starting text you want to use.

Comment: Can we use multiple regexes at the same time on a single sentence? If I use "5. Consider the task in Figure 8.11, which are balanced in fig 99.2 in the question" the first time as string, then I use " 5. Consider the task in Figure 8.11, which are balanced in fig 99.2". This will require different regex codes both the time.  Can I use multiple regexes so that if there is a different string every time I need not write regex codes again ?

Comment: Hmmm...the call to `re.findall` by default will find as many matches as possible.  As for the regex, it is geared to find a single number bulleted item.

Comment: @VipulPriyadarshi Why would you need a different regex for the two strings? The same regex would work for both strings. Please post a new question with a reproducible example that demonstrates the scenario where you actually need multiple regexes.

Comment: Understood. I could possible make use of try and catch for the same using functions. Thanks for your time :) @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Your regex doesn't actually produce the expected output, which should not have a leading space.

Comment: @VipulPriyadarshi No, not here.  Please ask a new question.

Comment: Cool.  :) @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1):

@TimBiegeleisen's answer works, but is somewhat verbose due to the fact that using `re.findall` would require repeating the pattern of the bullet point as a start and as a lookahead in the end.

For the purpose of finding strings between repeating patterns (bullet points in this case) it may be simpler to use `re.split` instead. Slice the resulting list to discard the first item since we don't need what comes before the first bullet point:

```
re.split(r'\d+\.(?!\d)\s*', s)[1:]
```

This returns:

```
['Consider the task in Figure 8.11, which are balanced in fig 99.2']
```

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't know there are so many ways within regex to solve this